# Java error variable not found symbol not found

Tags: java, oop

Hello I've a error code in java while I try to run this program it states cannot find symbol but I declared everything and Idk what's going on.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Programa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
    String arreglo[];
    Scanner dato=new Scanner(System.in);
    arreglo = new String[10];
    for(int a=1;a<10;a++){
        System.out.printf("Dale el nombre de la persona:");
        arreglo[a]=dato.nextLine();
        }

for (int a=1;a<10;a++){
        System.out.printf("%s%8s\n", a,arreglo(a));
        }
    }
}
```

This is on the variable arreglo(a)

Comment: Typo: `arreglo(a)` → `arreglo[a]`

Answer (score -1):

Because, you are using `()` to access array values, you must use `[]` for arrays:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Programa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String arreglo[];
        Scanner dato=new Scanner(System.in);
        arreglo = new String[10];
        for(int a=1;a<10;a++){
            System.out.printf("Dale el nombre de la persona:");
            arreglo[a]=dato.nextLine();
        }

        for (int a=1;a<10;a++){
            System.out.printf("%s%8s\n", a,arreglo[a]);
        }
    }
}
```